# Angular 2: cannot get two ways binding to work in custom component

Tags: angular, custom-component

I'm trying to make a simple angular 2 component displaying a switch button. 
It's almost working, except the parent value is not updated when using ngModel.

Here's my custom component:

```ts
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-switch',
template:` 
<label class="switch">
  <input id="switch" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label> `,   
styleUrls: ['./switch.component.css']
})
export class SwitchComponent {

    checkValue:boolean;
    @Output() checkChange = new EventEmitter();

    @Input()
    get checked() {
      return this.checkValue;
    }

    set checked(val) {
       this.checkValue = val;
       this.checkChange.emit(this.checkValue);
       console.log("from switch: value = " + this.checkValue);    
    }
}
```

Here's the parent component with 2 instances of my custom child component. 
- the first instance works fine but uses separated property [] and event () binding
- the second one is using two ways bindings [()] but is not working. Any idea what am I missing?

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:`
  <app-switch [checked]="checkValue" (checkChange)="onCheckChanged($event)"></app-switch>
  <div>checkBox :<span>{{checkValue}}</span></div>
  <hr/>
  <app-switch [(checked)]="switchValue" ></app-switch>
  <div>checkBox :<span>{{switchValue}}</span></div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  checkValue:boolean = false;
  switchValue:boolean = false;

  onCheckChanged($event){
    console.log("from AppComponent : " + $event);
    this.checkValue = $event;

  }
}
```

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second instance would require an output `checkedChange` event emitter since you're binding to the `checked` property. The naming is slightly off (`checkChange` vs `checkedChange`) so it won't allow for the two way binding that you have set up.

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/32ewdzZjtrQqA8vljARA?p=preview)

Comment: So if I understand correctly the output variable is actually the concatenation of the Input variable name + "Change" ?

Comment: Yes. This is a specific naming convention that is set up for binding against the same property name.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way